# An entropy-like measure for a pure state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavefunction, entropy, probability

It came to my mind that can we describe the flatness of a pure quantum state $\psi$ in terms of an entropy-like measure? Obviously, a Dirac delta -like distribution $|\psi|^2$ has a low "entropy", and the even distribution has a high "entropy". Since wave packets spread over time, our entropy-like measure $S(t)$ should be a non-decreasing function.

I would suggest that we sum over all the possible variances (and hope that the sum makes sense), that is

$$S(t) = \int \int (x-y)^2|\psi(x,t)|^2 dxdy.$$

---

**EDIT**: Perhaps it is possible to describe the flatness in position and momentum at the same time. The minimum value should be somehow related to the uncertainty principle. A wild suggestion might be

$$S(t) = \int \int (x-y)^2|\psi(x,t)|^2 dxdy + \int \int (p-y)^2|\phi(p,t)|^2 dpdy$$

that (I think) has the following compact form

$$S(t)=\int \int (x-y)^2(|\psi(x,t)|^2 + |\hat{\psi}(\hbar x,t)|^2) dxdy.$$

Comment: Why not just use Shannon entropy, $S=-\int dx\,\rho(x)\log\rho(x)$? Here $\rho = \psi^*\psi$. It doesn't really make sense to define entropy for a pure state because it is completely basis dependent, but if you insist on it, I see no reason to go beyond traditional definitions.

Comment: Also, that "wave packets spread over time" is just not true. They have a minimum spread at some time, yes, but they spread when you move away from that instant, both future and past. QM is reversible.

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti Ok. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti The entropy of a quantum state, at least the von Neumann entropy, is completely basis-independent.

Comment: @Hulkster What is the question here, actually? There are various definition of quantum entropies already...

Comment: @TobiasFünke yes, but it involves diagonalizing the density operator, and is zero for pure states. What Hulkster is looking for is something that describes the spread of pure wavefunction states in an "entropic" fashion, I guess.

Comment: So monitor the Shannon entropy for normalized Gaussians of various widths....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Apparently the entropy is just a log-function of variance.

Comment: Yes! broad distributions have less information...

Comment: Actually, in phase space, you may account for the information lost in the classical limit [this way](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9entropy.pdf).

Comment: @TobiasFünke For what Hulkster wants I think the entropy is basis dependent (obviously this is not a standard definition of entropy). For example, I think Hulkster would want to assign a large entropy to a broad wavefunction in the position basis because the wave function would be very spread out, even though the same state in the momentum basis would be very narrow and therefore have a very small entropy in the momentum basis. In other words I think they effectively want to define $S=- \int |\psi|^2 \log |\psi|^2$, where the integral is done in some basis.

Comment: @Andrew It seems like there is really no way that $S \stackrel{?}{=}-\int |\psi|^2 \log|\psi|^2$ makes sense. Even for a pure state the density matrix in the position basis is not diagonal, and so the product in the von neumann entropy is not the product of diagonal entries. The von neumann entropy for a pure state in the position basis is $S=-\int dx dy \psi(x)\psi^*(y)\langle y| \log(\hat \rho)|x\rangle $.

Comment: @hft I agree, I'm just stating my reading of what the OP wants. (An entropy which is large when the pure state has a large variance in some basis). In particular I don't think they are looking for the von Neumann entropy.

Comment: @Andrew OK, I see. But if that is the case, then OP can really use anything that OP wants. The example OP provided (with a squared difference) is probably easier for OP to understand than your example (with a log). Given that the example with the log is not really entropy, there is no real reason to choose a log function over any other function. Ultimately, I guess OP just asked a bad question. (Yes, there are bad questions ;).)

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I see. Thanks for the elaboration.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the concept of [Wehrl entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrl_entropy).

The Husimi Q-symbol of a state (pure or mixed) is defined as $\mathcal Q(q,p) = \langle q,p \vert \rho \vert q,p \rangle$, where $\vert q,p \rangle$ are the coherent states. Then the Wehrl entropy is defined as
$$ S_W = -k_B \int \mathcal Q(q,p) \ln \mathcal Q(q,p)\, \frac{\mathrm dq \mathrm dp}{2\pi\hbar} $$
The Wehrl entropy is bounded from below by the usual von Neumann entropy, $S_W \geq S$. It is also bounded by $S_W \geq k_B$ with $S_W = k_B$ if and only if the state is a pure coherent state. In other words, the "most peaked" pure states (in phase space) have the lowest Wehrl entropy.

Note that not everything called "entropy" makes sense as an entropy from a thermodynamic point of view. If you write down a Lindblad equation for a quantum harmonic oscillator and define entropy production as $\sigma = \dot S_W  + \dot Q / T$ as usual, you will find that $\sigma$ can become negative, violating the second law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

> An entropy measure for a pure state?

We already have [a perfectly good definition of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) for any state whether mixed or pure:

$$
S = -\text{Tr}(\rho\ln(\rho)) = -\sum_i p_i \ln(p_i)\;.
$$

For a pure state the entropy is zero (since one of the $p_i=1$ and all the rest are zero):
$$
S_{\text{pure}} = -\text{Tr}(\rho_{\text{pure}}\ln(\rho_{\text{pure}})) = -\sum_i p_i \ln(p_i) = -1 \times 0 = 0\;.
$$

---

Given the extreme confusion on this website and elsewhere regarding the meaning of the word "entropy," I not recommend introducing yet another definition for that word. Make whatever definition you would like, but please don't call it "entropy" unless that is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

For a wave packet entropy can be defined as that of the continuous probability distribution (see [Differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy)):
$$
w(x,t)=|\psi(x,t)|^2,\\
H(t)=-\int dx  w(x)\log w(x)
$$
But, of course, this has meaning very different from thermodynamic entropy.